# Are player participants notified if their battle gets on TV Royale?

Tags: clash-royale

Clash Royale sometimes broadcasts interesting battles from each arena to the TV Royale listings.  If a particular battle makes it to TV Royale, are the participating players informed that their battle was featured?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you and your whole clan will be notified via push notifications that a battle including a clanmate has been featured.

From the [February 2, 2016 patch notes](https://clashroyale.com/blog/release-notes/coming-soon-clash-royale-update):

> Push Notifications: New "A Clanmate's battle is now featured in TV
>   Royale!" notification

Answer (score 0):

Yes, including those of your Clanmates.